# What is the meaning of “next frequency” in PDC？

Tags: airport, radio-communications, clearance

When we get pdc we see next frequency,For example  121.4
Sometimes it is the frequency of clearance,but sometimes is the frequency of departure.
WHY?Which frequency should it be?

Comment: Hi Afanti, welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com! Can you explain what  PDC is? Perhaps give an example (screenshot, picture, verbatim text) to provide context to your question. It will increase the chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: And are you seeing this in actual PDCs, or in a flight simulator PC game?  It makes a difference...

Comment: I use PDC some (CPDLC more often), and that "next frequency" line isn't something I recall seeing.  Please provide a screenshot of an example, and tell us where you're getting this (i.e. what country/airport).  This may be something used locally in certain places; in the US, I've not seen it.

Comment: In east asia airport,For example VHHH RJTT,We request PDC(Pre-depart clearance) via DCL,We get the message like:"Clear to destination Via....NEXT FRQ 121.4",Sometimes the Frequency  is delivery but sometimes the frequency is departure,Which frequency should it be? Is there any regulation about it?

Comment: Are you getting the "next freq" message at many airports, in multiple countries? Possibilities would include, Country (or airport) A uses that for one thing, while B uses it for another, ***or*** it shows Clearance Delivery in cases where that's your next required call, but Departure otherwise. Does it ever give a Ramp or Ground Control freq? Until somebody else who flies in that region can chime in, best advice is to see if you can spot a pattern to it.

Comment: I do know how to send a picture but I have a pdc printed: 
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FROM LFPG
DEPARTURE CLEARANCE
CLD 1117 220222 LFPG PDC 040
XXX7224 CLRD TO TJAA OFF 27L VIA RANUS5A SQUAWK 5062 ADT 11:30 NEXT FREQ 121.810 TSAT 11:30 CONFIRM FULLY READY ON 121.730
(RECEIVED AT 1117Z)
STS:OPEN
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: the 121.810 here is GROND FREQ